# Functions, timing, calling in order and global variables

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions called one after the other, x and y are global variables.

```
 function setVariables() {
     x = 2;
     y = 10;
 };

 function useVariables() {
     console.log(x);
     console.log(y);
 };
```

Say I call these two functions in a document ready function one after the other. Is `setVariables` guaranteed to "finish" before `useVariables` is called? Or, given that `setVariables` could be long and take some time to run, could you end up in a situation where `useVariables` tries to use these global variables before `setVariables` has had a chance to set them?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the real problem you have, not the way you want to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. It's not possible to have code running in parallel. The two functions will always execute in sequence.

It's important to distinguish between **parallelism** and **asynchrony**.

- **Parallelism** is the possibility of code running simultaneously in different threads or different processes. When you have parallelism, you have to start worrying about race conditions and synchronization of shared state.

  As a single-threaded language, parallelism does not come into play in JavaScript.<sup>†</sup>
- **Asynchrony** is the ability to have code run in an unpredictable order at unpredictable times. If you use `setTimeout` or setup AJAX callbacks or register event handlers, you don't have a guarantee of ordering. When you register multiple timeout callbacks, for instance, you should not assume they execute in one particular order.

  Asynchrony does not necessarily mean that code will execute in parallel. In other languages it might, but in JavaScript it won't. You don't have to be concerned about variables you're using in one event handler being changed by some other event handler. While your code is running, it is the *only* code running.

---

<sup>†</sup> [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) complicate the answer. Web workers provide parallelism by allowing work to be done in background threads. These threads can only interface with the main thread via asynchronous events, though. There is no shared data. The main thread does not otherwise see these background threads. It can still safely pretend the world is single-threaded.

Comment: So you can guarantee order here? `window.setTimeout(foo, 0); window.setTimeout(bar, 0);`

Comment: That's not the question that was asked. The question says that the functions are called one after the other in a document ready function.

Comment: `+1`ing because answer now explains asynchrony in a way which lets OP know you can't **always** assume function invocation order, but for the majority of code there is no doubt.

Comment: Those asynchronous functions that you refer to ate provided by the implementation, be it the DOM or Node. JavaScript by itself is not capable of asynchronous operation and is single threaded indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
setVariables()
useVariables()
```

setVariables() shall and will always be executed and finished before the next line (useVariables()) is executed.

Comment: timeouts and intervals also won't guarantee order, basically anything "asynchronous"

Comment: @raina77ow we don't see any code for how OP is invoking them; why should we assume there isn't any?

Comment: @raina77ow Because we assume he'd like to learn if the contrary is possible.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by asynchronous code?

Comment: @raina77ow see Paul S.'s comment.

Comment: @OliverJ90 Any code written exactly as your example is so-called 'synchronous'. The computer will read your code line-by-line. But using a timeout, setTimeout(), will have code executed later, that is, out-of-sync. Also anything using event listeners like mything.attachEvent('mousedown') is also asynchronous.